# How to parse a webpage in Ruby without any library or gem?

Tags: ruby, api, https

I want to use the API of a website in a Ruby script, and the only return from the API is a number through the HTTPS protocol. Nothing more, not even tags or something, so I was wondering if there is a way to get that number in a string or integer in my script without using any XML parsing livrary or gem like REXML or hpricot or libXML, because the webpages that I want to parse are, as I said, extremely basic...

Comment: didn't knew where to start so I searched on google, and because everything that I found needed to install libraries or gems, I haven't tried anything yet....

Comment: You shouldn't worry about installing gems, that's how it works here. Before you start something look if a gem already does it. Then look if more gems do it, and use the one with the most forks/stars on github. You'll save much time.

Comment: @Micka that's great, but I see that it is pointless to install any gem for such a simple job, as long as the webpages that I want to parse look like https://dogechain.info/chain/Dogecoin/q/addressbalance/DTnt7VZqR5ofHhAxZuDy4m3PhSjKFXpw3e ..... That is just a simple numer, without anything else in the page or in thr code..... There has to be a quick n dirty yet effective way tp do it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand. A request to `https://www.website.com/api/getid` return `2`.

Then, I guess this would do:

```rb
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'

def open(url)
  Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end

response = open("https://www.website.com/api/getid")
```

## EDIT

You'll find much usefull examples [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html).

As it is mentioned in the link above, [HTTParty](http://johnnunemaker.com/httparty/) is quite popular. An example:

```rb
require 'httparty'

response = HTTParty.get('http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json')
puts response.body, response.code, response.message, response.headers.inspect
```

Comment: the first solution you provided given me an error about using a HTTP request instead of a HTTPS one, but the second one works! thanks!

Comment: Both `open("http://stackoverflow.com/")` and `open("https://dogechain.info/chain/Dogecoin/q/addressbalance/DTnt7VZqR5ofHhAxZuDy4m3PhSjKFXpw3e")` works in my `irb` console.
Try `require 'net/http'` instead of `https` for http requests.